# Angular Universal and the BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I had created a website in Angular with Angular Universal for SSR. The problem is: the `BehaviorSubject` loss its data every time I reload the page or switch into the another. And this happens only when running an SSR version of the app – when I run `ng serve`, it compiles, runs and works properly, as expected. Also, the BehaviorSubject works well after `NgOnInit`, because of this factory in my AppModule:

```js
export function appInitializerFactory(authService: AuthService) {
  return () => authService.checkUserOnFirstLoad();
}
```

And here's my AuthService:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  private user$ = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private tokenStorage: TokenStorage) {}

  setUser(user: User | null): void {
    if (user) this.user$.next(user);
  }

  getUser(): Observable<User | null> {
    return this.user$.asObservable();
    // ^^^^ value of this returns null every time
  }

  me(): Observable<User> {
    const token: string | null = this.tokenStorage.getToken();
    if (token === null) return EMPTY;
    return this.http.get<MeOutput>(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/auth/me`).pipe(
      tap(({ userDetails }) => this.setUser(userDetails)),
      pluck('user')
    );
  }

  checkUserOnFirstLoad(): Promise<User> {
    return this.me().toPromise();
  }
}
```

Please, help me understand this behavior.

Comment: If anyone needs a full code: https://github.com/cholewka/tic-tac-toe.git

Comment: What do you mean by "loss its data every time I reload the page or switch into the another." ? Angular works exacly the same as without SSR except if you use transfertState. PS: localStorage doesn't work on server side and use SSR only for public pages

Comment: I used `localStorage` polyfill in server.ts and it works fine. And what I mean of data loss - when I add some `console.log`s for debug in `getUser()` method, the `getUser()` returns valid user-data only after Angular's initial (`NgOnInit`) after the factory process and executes `checkUserOnFirstLoad` method. And then, it's setting user via `setUser()`, but after I reload the page or click a link - `getUser()` method is returning null.

Comment: And what to you have if you add a console log into your `me()` function. Do you have a token after reload ?

Comment: I've added a console.log into the `me()` function, and it returns valid data. Yes, I have token after a reload.

Comment: where exactly is the problem? In the guard that uses the getUser? If so, add in the guard a `filter (v => v! == null)`

Comment: Using localStorage won't work with universal, using the polyfill means that the execution won't fail but it will not save the data